# console.log logging empty values unless specific value is specified

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer

I am using Node.js and Puppeteer and have it set up to load a specific page.
This page renders new elements every second and I am adding a `MutationObserver` to listen and have a function trigger when new elements are added.

If I for example try `getItem(mutation)` it will log `{}`, an empty object

But if I try to `getItem(mutation.addedNodes[0].textContent)` it will log `'NewElement'`, which is the text content of the new element.

Also trying anything between `mutation` all the way to `mutation.addedNodes[0].textContent` results in empty objects/arrays.

Why does the first example not log anything, the object has values since I can reach them by being more specific. Why does it not log the values it holds and the structure of the object.

```
const runPuppeteer = async (url: string) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 })
  await page.goto(url);

  await page.exposeFunction('getItem', (a: any) => {
    console.log(a)
  })

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      for (const mutation of mutations) {
        getItem(mutation.addedNodes[0].textContent) // <--- My question
      }
    })
    observer.observe(document.querySelector('#chatDiv'), { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true })
  })
}

let myPage = 'http://localhost:3000/home'
runPuppeteer(myPage)
```

Comment: What changes happen to the observed element?

Comment: As far as I know nothing. This is just used to send the value from the browser that is in puppeteers context to my Node.js context.
So an element is created with document.createElement and then appended to the document with appendChild.
I try to get a MutationObserver to notify my Node.js context when those elements are added. It does not change the element afaik.

Comment: @permeil400 Why do you want to log mutation record objects to the console running your Node process?

Answer (score 0):

Not all properties of all objects will print with console.log, particularly with builtins. If you want to know all the properties on an object, you  can try Object.keys(o) or Reflect.ownKeys

There are also serialization libraries and "objectify" libraries that will try to turn a complex class instance into an explicit json-like Object.

Sometimes classes will have getters, a number will be wrapped as an object, objects will be proxied, etc, so in general the console.log output can be extremely incomplete